# ListView Divider not shown on click-disabled elements on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView populated with several elements. If a condition is met, some of this elements will become click-disabled. Also, I made a custom divider for my ListView. The problem is that, only on Lollipop version of Android, if an element becomes disabled, the separator is not shown anymore. On other version of Android it works perfectly, the problem occurs only on Android 5.0+.

**code to disable items**

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    Account account = this.items.get(position);
    if (account.getActive.equals("Inactive")) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**ListView xml**

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@drawable/separator_listview"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
</ListView>
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Height and width of the listview must always be match_parent.

Comment: @Kartheek MATCH_PARENT was my initial approach. but still with same result.

Answer (score 0):

For adding the divider for the `ListView` you need to create a drawable.
**res/drawable/divider.xml**

```
<shape
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@color/custom_color" />
    <gradient android:height="1dp" />
</shape>
```

**Listview.xml**

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@drawable/drawable"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I created the custom drawable which I applied on my xml code.